# How to make a Checkbutton/box change a text file on-click? (Using Python and tkinter library)

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, save, text-files

So, I decided to make this project of building a program so I could have a record of my books, which of them I borrowed, which I've read, etc. For the "database" I'm using .txt files, which contain the book titles, authors, etc. One at a line and all a book shares the same line with it's author, but they are in separate files. So, for example, I've got:

```
FILE A:                     |              FILE B:
Harry Potter                |           J.K. Rowling
The Fellowship of the Ring  |         J.R.R. Tolkien
```

And so on with all the other Info.
Now, I've added a checkbutton for each book, so that I can mark the ones I've read, and created a .txt file called read with "SELECTED" or "NOT-SELECTED" in each line to represent the state of the Checkbutton.
I, then add the checkbuttons to the program through a for loop that runs through the read.txt file and adds as many check buttons as there are lines in the file. If the line in the file reads "SELECTED", then it sets the checkbutton as selected (`checkbutton.selected()`), else it just creates the checkbutton.
Now, what I want is that the program will change the line in the read.txt file as soon as the corresponding-line button is pressed, so, if I press the button for Harry Potter, for example, the first line in read.txt will be changed to "SELECTED", and if I click it again it will be changed back to "NOT-SELECTED".
What I first thought about doing was to create a list with the values of each check button, and then when any check button gets pressed, it will call a function that creates a new list, with the new values of each button. It would, then, compare the two lists and make the necessary changes to the first, then changing the file. The problem is, I have no idea of how to create the secont list, to compare, so I'm looking for help on how to do it. If someone has a better idea, though, it would be more than welcome.

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Your problem ir more conceptual than related to programming, since using plain text files in a situation where [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) can do the job perfectly implies a lot of overhead. Unfortunately, it is too localized and I don't think it can be a reference for future users, so in my opinion this post is out of the scope of StackOverflow. As a general advice I strongly recommend you to use a database in your project and get rid of txt files.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's just that I'm quite a beginer, so I was just trying the simplest way. If possible, could you tell me something about sqlite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) module rather than plain text files. It handles data stored in the Comma Separated Value spreadsheet format, and for basic fields like `title`, `author`, `is_read`, `borrowed_from`, etc. it should work fine, and is easier to deal with than `sqlite3` in that you don't need to learn SQL or design a database schema. There are some limitations though, so I highly recommend reading through the docs I linked to and seeing if it fits your needs. If your project gets more complex, then reading up on [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html) is your best bet.